# Create a sample Jasper report manually

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I am trying to learn JasperReports. So far, I have figured out that JasperReports can be integrated with NetBeans and for that, I used several tutorials but not able to get the correct code. I want to create the report manually .

I have created the sample application and it contains code:

```
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
 public class JavaApplication7 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


String reportSource = "./report.temp.result/newXMLDocument.xml";
String reportDest = "./report.template/HelloReportWorld.html";

HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

try
{
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

JasperPrint jasperPrint =
    JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);

JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
  }
  catch (JRException ex)
  {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

i have also create the sample file for the template that include the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE jasperReport
 PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" 
 "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

 <jasperReport name="HelloReportWorld">
  <detail>
     <band height="200">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="500" height="20"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Hello Report World!]]></text>
        </staticText>
     </band>
   </detail>
 </jasperReport>
```

this is the xml file as i read in the tutorial that xml file can be used  for that creating the jasper report (it slows the compilation process ) ----is it ok

i have used the empty file for the creating the .jrxml with the same code but i think that i might be missing the XML design document in that and  i can't able to figure it out  from where to get that xml design document and where to add that as well in the netbeans

i am trying to run the main file to get the output but i get the following list of errors

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:68)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:94)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:71)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperCompileManager.java:84)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:459)
at javaapplication7.JavaApplication7.main(JavaApplication7.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 8 more
  Java Result: 1
```

these are the list of error which i find while running the main file 
the issues i face

1) am i following the right approach for creating the jasper report

2) can i use the xml file for the format specification in the jasper report creation

3) how can i create the .jrxml file and use in the code as the template in the jasper report and for that where i have to insert the xml design document if i am missing that in the code

4)i also want to know how to integrate the jasper report with the data source like postgers manually

thankyou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these jar file in your class path.

1. Common bean util
2. commons collections
3. commons digester
4. commons logging
5. hibernate annotation
6. itext
7. servlet api

For using postgres or any other database you need to use ireport. It will provide you to better way to use database manually.

Enjoy.